# EVR custom presenter not skipping frames

Tags: directshow, ms-media-foundation

I have an EVR custom presenter component inside an Unity3D application which is running with vSync enabled.

If the component plays a video with, say, 60fps and the monitor refresh rate is at 60Hz as well, the video playback is too slow. This happens for each case where the video fps is equal or larger than the monitor refresh rate.

When I ask the graph for the current time during playback, the time itself proceeds correctly until it reachs the end of the video. From this moment on the time doesn't change further, it keeps its value. However, pictures received from the evr engine drift apart - they fall behind the time. When the time "stops", the video keeps running until it actually finishes. Only then there's an EC_COMPLETE event in the graph.

With regard to the presenting engine all samples but the first few appear to be late. The delta time steadily increases. I don't have a growing queue - this must be inside EVR.

Is skipping of frames something I can implement inside the custom presenter? Or is it a property I could set?

As soon as I disable vSync, the video runs in correct speed, but this solution/workaround is not possible for the application.

Comment: How do you enable/disable vsync? The custom EVR presenter supplied by Windows SDK doesn't allow enabling/disabling vsync. And if vsync is enabled globally (by the graphics card adapter config) then the csutom EVR presenter will wait during the Present call for a vsync. This might be the cause for time drift. You might try to use D3DPRESENT_DONOTWAIT in Present call to see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts! vSync is enabled/disabled through a Unity3D property (QualitySettings.vSyncCount). My custom presenter simply stretches the EVR sample onto a texture that is supplied by Unity3D. However, I even tried to comment this stretch-blit call for testing purposes. Then the screen/texture stays blank, but EC_COMPLETE is still received much too late. D3DPRESENT_DONOTWAIT sounds like it could help, but the actual Present call is done from Unity3D.
Will every call into Direct3D be blocked while the engine waits for the vSync?

Comment: Yes, but you might also have some timestamp issue with your samples. Or you might need to implement frame skipping inside your EVR presenter before calling StretchRect (I suppose?), by checking if the timestamp is late before doing it. If it is late simply skip StretchRect.

Comment: Hmmm, that's hard to tell. The code works fine as long as the fps of video is smaller than the monitor refresh rate. The timestamps should come from the decoder, IMO. And a couple of those I've been watching appear to be correct.
But if indeed every call into the D3D objects is blocked, this could explain the behaviour.

Comment: It seems I missed your update to the comment... I already tried doing nothing when the timestamp is late. But it seems the EVR keeps sending samples.

Comment: You might also have other D3D calls that are also affected by the vsync in Present. It's normal that EVR will keep providing samples of course.